# Integrate Salesforce Marketing cloud with ecommerce process

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, e-commerce

We are going to start a salesforce marketing cloud implementation project and I have this use case where we want to identify customers that are on our e-commerce process and that drop after the form fill. We want to communicate to those customers with specific emails after they drop.

My question is, do we have a technical way to implement such use case? and what type of component should we use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Transactional Email feature for this. Email templates are stored in Marketing Cloud, and you can populate them with data from the e-commerce process.

I believe what you want to achieve is abandoned cart functionality?

You can pass on information on cart content in JSON format in the REST cll, and iterate through the JSON object using AMPscript.

An example on triggering transactional emails with REST API can be found here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/messageDefinitionSends.htm

Comment: Do you know if we can arrive to the same result by just integrating Salesforce web analytics to our e-commerce website ? The documentation says that we can act on the tracking results...

Comment: Yes, but you will need to set up the full Predictive Intelligence feature, along with integration for your [product catalogue](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/personalization_builder/personalization_builder_prerequisites/catalog/)

Answer (score 1):

Running a similar project at the moment. In the client's use case, transactional emails are fired by hybris (client's e commerce engine) using to send trigger (SOAP API Call) an email and add the customer details to a data extension. You can extend this with REST Calls to various other modules (e.g. Journey Builder).

For getting familiar with API calls, visit: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm

Answer (score 0):

So we are going to use predictive intelligence as we need some other aspects of the product like banner display on the website.

Thank you for your help :-)